# Charging of Li-ion battery fails after voltage was cut-off

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, battery-charging

I designed a charging PCB using this Li-Ion charger IC:
https://datasheet.octopart.com/BQ24072RGTT-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-5404322.pdf

In my tests, the charging works as expected when using unprotected batteries. However, when I try to charge a battery equipped with an undervoltage protection circuit that was discharged to such an extent that the voltage was automatically cut-off at 2.5V, the charging process fails. The charger IC doesn't provide any charging voltage (to be more precise, it provides only a charging voltage of 0.7V). Does anyone know a possible explanation for this?

I used this battery:

https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Keeppower%2018650%203120mAh%20P1831R%20(Black)%202017%20UK.html

Comment: You do not tell us (and need to) WHICH IC you are using (the datasheet cited covers 4), your circuit (the component values used affect results (as you'd expect)) , your Vin  || The datasheet seems WRONG re UVLO BUT a voltage under about 2.5V is deemed dangerously low by some chargers. The cell itself may have tripped an internal cutout. || Wear safety goggles. Do this in a fire and explosion agnostic location. Wear safety goggles. Use a 3V to 4V supply. DO NOT EXCEED 4V. Wear safety goggles.  ...

Comment: ... Wear safety goggles.  Join negative of supply and cell. Place a 1k resistor between cell + and supply +. Watch and record cell V+. IF cell V+ rises slowly to 3V or better, retry in charger. If it does not change at all after say 1 hour, bury at crossroads with a stake though its heart while wearing protective clothing and safety goggles.